# How do I pass both read_html and html_table through lapply on a string of files?

Tags: r, lapply

I have a batch of tables that happen to be stored as .html. I want to read the tables in R, perform some minor cleanup, and then save these as .csv.

I'm stuck on the first part of this. When I perform the following operations on a single .html, everything works fine:

```
read_html("file1.html") %>%
html_table(header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

However, when I attempt to call lapply I get an error:

```
lapply(filenames, read_html %>%
html_table(header = TRUE, fill = TRUE))
#where 'filenames' comes from a list.files operation
```

To me everything after 'filenames,' is still the second argument of lapply(X, FUN) but clearly it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the error message? Have you tried it without the pipe operator?

Comment: Error in UseMethod("html_table") : 
 no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "function".   And I considered trying without the pipe operator but wasn't sure how to wrap both of these operations.

Comment: @Albatrosspro Just use the longer form of `lapply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the more verbose form of `lapply` should work:

```
lapply(filenames, function(x) {
    read_html(x) %>% html_table(header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
})
```